# Avro Schema array without name

Tags: avro

## Question 1

I'm wondering whether below schema is valid or not for an Avro schema. Note that it is missing name in the first object of fields array.

```
{
  "name": "AgentRecommendationList",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
      {
          "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                  "name": "friend",
                  "type": "record",
                  "fields": [
                      {
                          "name": "Name",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "phoneNumber",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "email",
                          "type": "string"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Which actually designed to target below kind of data

```
[
        {
            "Name": "1",
            "phoneNumber": "2",
            "email": "3"
        },
        {
            "Name": "1",
            "phoneNumber": "2",
            "email": "3"
        },
        {
            "Name": "1",
            "phoneNumber": "2",
            "email": "3"
        }
 ]
```

Based on reading below, seems like array without name like this are not permitted

[Avro Schema failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831992/avro-schema-failure)

```
There is no way to define and avro schema with an array without a field name.
```

https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#schema_complex

```
name: a JSON string providing the name of the field (required), and
```

I'm suspecting that below is the correct ones

```
{
  "name": "AgentRecommendationList",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
      {
          "name": "friends",
          "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                  "name": "friend",
                  "type": "record",
                  "fields": [
                      {
                          "name": "Name",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "phoneNumber",
                          "type": "string"
                      },
                      {
                          "name": "email",
                          "type": "string"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

And it should have a data like below, in order to do the avro conversion successfully

```
{
  "friends": [
      {
          "Name": "1",
          "phoneNumber": "2",
          "email": "3"
      },
      {
          "Name": "1",
          "phoneNumber": "2",
          "email": "3"
      },
      {
          "Name": "1",
          "phoneNumber": "2",
          "email": "3"
      }
  ]
}
```

## Question 2

Does below schema is a valid schema? This target the array without name in first example...

```
{
  "name": "AgentRecommendationList",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
      "name": "friend",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
          {
              "name": "Name",
              "type": "string"
          },
          {
              "name": "phoneNumber",
              "type": "string"
          },
          {
              "name": "email",
              "type": "string"
          }
      ]
   }
}
```

I will appreciate if anyone can confirm my understanding... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1...

Everything you have written is right. The first schema, as you mentioned, is not valid because each field within a record needs to have a `name`. The corrected schema is valid and the corrected data is right for the updated schema.

For question 2...

The schema in question two is valid, but the `AgentRecommendationList` name will get ignored. Arrays don't have names. This might sound strange after looking at the examples in question one, but in those the `name` is part of the `field` specification, not the array.